# Why does eta-conversioned function have different type?

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

When I load below haskell code file by ':l' command in GHCi.

```
add1 x y = x + y
add2 = \x -> \y -> x + y
```

Type of add1 and add2 is like below.

```
add1 :: Num a => a -> a -> a
add2 :: Integer -> Integer -> Integer
```

Why do they have different type???

UPDATE

When I input below codes in GHCi, they have same type 'Num a => a -> a -> a'.

```
let add1 x y = x + y
let add2 = \x -> \y -> x + y
```

Comment: They have the same type on GHCi 7.8.4 and 7.10.

Comment: https://wiki.haskell.org/Monomorphism_restriction + defaulting rules

Comment: Isn't there a canonical monomorphism restriction question/answer? This question gets asked *all the time*.

Comment: @AndrásKovács When I define function using let in GHCi, they have same type. But when I load source code file using ":l" command, they have different type. I test it on GHC 7.8.3.

Comment: @Philip JF I will check monomorphism restriction as your comment. Thanks.

Comment: @Bakuriu: Probably, but [none that's](http://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=monomorphism) easy to find if you don't know the term "monomorphism".

Comment: @Zeta Your comment is correct. I can't find answer because I don't know that term.